# Returning all the x coordinates where the graph cuts a y coordinate

Tags: r

I've got the first line down which is defining the function:

```
f <- function(x) 3034*log(x)+2305.84*log(1-x)-1517*log(1-x)
```

Now the problem I'm having is I need to find all the `x` values where 
`f(x)=-1947.92` but I've got no idea what the command is to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would say you should use `uniroot()`, after modifying the function to return zero at the target, but that will be problematic here:

```
target <- -1947.92
f <- function(x) 3034*log(x)+2305.84*log(1-x)-1517*log(1-x) 
g <- function(x) f(x)-target
uniroot(g,interval=c(1e-4,1-1e-4))
## Error in uniroot(g, interval = c(1e-04, 1 - 1e-04)) : 
##   f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

What's going on is that your curve crosses zero in two places.  `uniroot()` requires that you *bracket* the root:

Let's take a look:

```
curve(g(x))
abline(h=0,col=2)
```

[image]

Zoom in:

```
curve(g(x),from=0.75,to=0.85)
abline(h=0,col=2)
```

[image]

Now we can either just eyeball this (i.e. use `interval=c(1e-4,0.8)` or `interval=c(0.8,1-1e-4)` depending on which root we're interested in) or find

```
opt1 <- optim(g,par=0.5,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=1e-4,upper=1-1e-4,
              control=list(fnscale=-1))  ## maximize rather than min
```

then use `opt1$par` as your cut-point.  (Or you could do some simple calculus: the maximum [point where the derivative wrt x is zero] is much easier to compute than the roots ...)

Alternatively, you could [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/1CbtNX8) ...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'd love to use calc here but the assignment specifies we need to use R as our tool to solve this problem (Even though it isnt taught in class).

Comment: You should really say when stuff is homework.  I prefer not to answer homework questions :-( ...

Comment: PS `optimize()` is more appropriate than `optim()` here